# Ignore NULL columns from the result in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, backend

I'm really new to Postgres and was wondering if there is an easy way to do this.
I have a table where I will only query a single row at a time. Every row is about a product and every column is basic nutritional info on the pack which looks like this:

[image: click here for image]

While querying a single row, I want to ignore all the columns that have null values and return the rest in a JSON format. I haven't found a good way to filter the null columns.

I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90858/postgres-multiple-columns-to-json) is how you convert the data to JSON in Postgres and it works well but because every product (row) will have different nutritional info (column) so I don't how to implement this.

If there is no way to implement this then can I send everything to the frontend and filter it there? Will that affect the performance a lot? I have about 150 columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the complete row to a JSON value without NULL values using `jsonb_strip_nulls()`

```
select jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(t))
from the_table t
where ...
```

`to_jsonb(t)` converts the complete row to a JSON value where the column name is the key. `jsonb_strip_nulls()` will then remove those keys with a NULL value.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, can't thank you enough.